# Export Yoast Keywords from MySQL/phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, plugin-wp-seo-yoast, phpmyadmin

I'd like to export all focus keywords from Yoast, as we're moving platforms to Craft CMS and using a similar tool, [Ethercreative's SEO tool](https://github.com/ethercreative/seo).

I'd love a good query to pull these from the database, matching on ID or some other shared table column so that I can import them into Craft's DB.

Answer (score 1):

This query pulls the post id, title, permalink, and focus keywords. You could modify this to pull the post meta description and title as well if you wanted. Change post_type to page if you want to pull pages.

```
SELECT wpp.post_title, wpp.ID, wpp.post_date, mt1.meta_value as focus_keyword,
       REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( wpo.option_value, '%year%', DATE_FORMAT(wpp.post_date,'%Y') ), '%monthnum%', DATE_FORMAT(wpp.post_date, '%m') ), '%day%', DATE_FORMAT(wpp.post_date, '%d') ), '%postname%', wpp.post_name ) AS permalink
  FROM wp_posts wpp
  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wpp.ID = mt1.post_id AND mt1.meta_key='_yoast_wpseo_focuskw')
  JOIN wp_options wpo
    ON wpo.option_name = 'permalink_structure'
 WHERE wpp.post_type = 'post'
   AND wpp.post_status = 'publish'
 ORDER BY wpp.post_date DESC;
```